# Getting data out of Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, windows-desktop-gadgets

i'm developing a windows desktop gadget for Google Analytics and I want to retrieve the data from Google Analytics.
Is there a way to get the data from Google Analytics in any form by any method?
prefered methods would be Javascript or Jquery.

thanks in advance :D

Comment: Any version to that story? `Google Tag Manager` for example or an older version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Google Analytics Core reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/) is what you are looking for.
A handy JavaScript tool is available with the [embed API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/).

Comment: Thanks, that was what I'm looking for. Can't get it working right now but I will keep trying... getting an 403.14 error never had one like that before :(